# Delphi и PrintScreen: Как повысить качество снимков?

Tags: delphi, c++

переменные:

```
 Canvas:TCanvas;
 ScreenV:HDC;
 i: String;
```

сам код:

```
ScreenV := GetDC(0);
Canvas:=TCanvas.Create();
Canvas.Handle:=ScreenV;
Image1.Canvas.Copyrect(Rect(0,0,Image1.Width,Image1.Height),
Canvas, Rect(0,0,Screen.Width,Screen.Height));
ReleaseDC(0,ScreenV);
Canvas.Free;

Label3.Caption:=IntToStr(StrToInt(Label3.Caption)+StrToINt(i));
files:=Edit3.Text+IntTOStr(StrToInt(Edit1.Text)+StrToInt(Label3.Caption))+'.jpg';
Image1.Picture.SaveToFile(files);
```

и вопрос: все работает, скринит, сохраняет, но один вопрос - как сделать качество изображений лучше?

Comment: Если бы Picture изображение было типа TJPEGImage, то у него есть свойство CompressionQuality.. надо только как-то превратить одно в другое.. может быть что-то типа MyJPG := TJPEGImage.Create; MyJPG.Assign(Image1.Picture)

Comment: эм.... непонятно ;D
еще использую - uses jpeg; мб для кого-то будет нужно...

Comment: Качество снимков может хромать из-за размеров Image, если они не равны размерам экрана. Можно не в сам Image сохранять результат, а в BitMap, например, а потом преобразовать в Jpeg и сохранить.